# java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected token: REFERENCES

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, postgresql

I'm getting an exception for my Create Statement query when using hibernate-sql mapping. Here is the create statement (Postgres) and the error it complains about.
Query:

```
CREATE TABLE translation (
translation_id INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('translation_seq'::regclass) PRIMARY KEY,
category TEXT NOT NULL,
sub_category TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
prod_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES product(product_id),
date_created DATE DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
expired BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL
);
```

Exception / failure in the Test:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: HypersonicAccessor.dbInitSchema() failure. 
at com.package1.package2.package3.database.HypersonicAccessor.dbInitSchema(HypersonicAccessor.java:210)
at com.package1.package2.package3.someDbConfig.initialize(ProdDbConfig.java:145)
at com.package1.package2.package3.backend.client.UpdaterTest.setUp(UpdaterTest.java:57)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected token: REFERENCES in statement 
[CREATE TABLE TRANSLATION (TRANSLATION_ID BIGINT NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY,
 CATEGORY VARCHAR NOT NULL,    SUB_CATEGORY VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL, 
  PROD_ID BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES]
at com.package1.package2.package3.database.HypersonicDatabase.execute(HypersonicDatabase.java:146)
at com.package1.package2.package3.database.HypersonicDatabase.runSqlScript(HypersonicDatabase.java:169)
at com.package1.package2.package3.database.HypersonicAccessor.runScriptList(HypersonicAccessor.java:123)
at com.package1.package2.package3.database.HypersonicAccessor.dbInitSchema(HypersonicAccessor.java:157)
```

Im not sure if my query is wrong or something else is. Any clue what could possibly be wrong ? This actually is the same issue with a few of my tests that previously were passing but now they are not.

Comment: Does table `Product` exists?

Comment: @lad2025 yes. Table Product exists. I did make sure all of that.

Comment: Are you running this as HQL?

Comment: @RohitJain This actually is a unit test that is failing. I have this .sql file that I am loading when I build my project. So yeah, not running it as HQL but as SQL. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: @noobcoder Can you show your unit test class, how you're loading the scripts?

Comment: I am thinking it is because for whatever reason I am not aware of, the "REFERENCES" should not be the way I have there. It should be separated out using Alter table clause and specify the referential integrity, and remove the references in the create statement. I could be wrong though. I'm trying to see if that fixes the problem. Ill post once I see it.

Comment: @RohitJain I found the issue. I think it was the problem with Hypersonic database not able to recognize the REFERENCES keyword along with the create statement. I removed the references in the same line and added an Alter statement to add the referential constraint. That worked for me. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Can you please provide the code that solved you issue ?